# Python 3.7 crashes after installing Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, crash, scrapy, pip, virtualenv

Python 3.7 crashes after installing Scrapy via `pip` on a virtual environment. There is no log, except a message that says *Python has stopped working*. I am on Windows 8.1. How can I solve this?

Comment: How did you install it? Via Anaconda or Miniconda or pip? See also https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows -- please provide some more information.

Comment: Just installed Scrapy directly into a virtualenv using pip install.

Comment: Have you read this? https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2881

Comment: How can I avoid the crash?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/3143 python 3.7 does not support Scrapy currently. Repair the python and restart.